# Query string parameter in ui-router urls?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have these states:

```
.state('quotes', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/quotes'
})
.state('quotes.new', {
  url: '/new',
  templateUrl: 'views/quote-form.html',
  controller: 'QuoteFormCtrl'
})
.state('quotes.new.customer', {
  url: '?customer',
  templateUrl: 'views/quote-form.html',
  controller: 'QuoteFormCtrl'
})
```

When I hit the URL `/quotes/new?customer=123` the ?customer query string is stripped off, and I am left at the `quotes.new` state.

What would make most sense to me is just adding a `params: ['customer']` to the `quotes.new` state definition, but that gives me an error complaining that I specify both url and params.

Any examples of what I'm trying to do would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should modify the `url` string property to include your `customer` query parameter, like this:

```
.state('quotes.new', {
  url: '/new?customer',
  templateUrl: 'views/quote-form.html',
  controller: 'QuoteFormCtrl'
});
```

Multiple parameters can be added by separating them with an `&`:

```
.state('mystate', {
  url: '/myState?paramOne&paramTwo
  //...
});
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be simpler than I was making it.

Comment: how does this work with `$state.go`?

`$state.go('quotes.new', {customer: 'dave'})` ?

Comment: [yup](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#go)

Comment: how does this work with multiple parameters in query string?  `url: '/new?customer&format'`?

Comment: So you can't expect a random query param in the url and access it?

Comment: Right, iirc you must expect them. See [state.go](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go) docs

Comment: @connorbode, as in the example here https://www.codelord.net/2015/06/20/simple-pagination-and-url-params-with-ui-router/