# Nested States and Query Parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

In my app, I'd like to have a separate view/controller for a child state with just a query param. Something along the lines of

```
.state('article') {
    url: '/articles/:articleID',
    controller: 'articleController'
}
.state('article.raw') {
    url: '?raw',
    controller: 'rawArticleController'
}
```

This works fine with the latest version of UI-Router, except that the query param `?raw` doesn't show up in the URI. E.g, if I go to the `article.raw` state with `{articleID: 'Hello'}`, I still see this

```
http://app/articles/Hello
```

Instead of this

```
http://app/articles/Hello?raw
```

I've searched around and found these related issues but they don't solve my problem. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

- [Query string parameter in ui-router urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461714/query-string-parameter-in-ui-router-urls)
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1670

Comment: try to add  url: .state('article.raw') {
    url: 'articalraw?raw'
    controller: 'rawArticleController'
}  and check

Comment: Hmm, doing that would change the value of `articleID` wouldn't it? So `/articles/Hello` be `/articles/Helloarticalraw?raw` in the child state :/

Comment: just simple one add infront /  like this  .state('article.raw') { url: '/articalraw?raw' controller: 'rawArticleController'

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIXAKydpKtTDl1D8hZJe?p=preview)

In general, it is very hard for UI-Router to understand url definition without a constant in it (i.e. just with a query string param)

So, we should either use some specific name

```
url: "/child?raw"
```

or at least "/"

```
     .state('article', {
        url: '/articles/:articleID',
        controller: 'articleController',
        templateUrl: "views/article.html",
      })
    .state('article.raw', {
        url: '/?raw',
        controller: 'rawArticleController',
        templateUrl: "views/raw.html",
    })
```

Now all these links will work

```
  <a ui-sref="article">
  <a ui-sref="article.raw">
  <a ui-sref="article({articleID: 1})">
  <a ui-sref="article({articleID: 22})">
  <a ui-sref="article.raw({articleID: 333, raw: 'someRaw'})">
  <a ui-sref="article.raw({articleID: 4444, raw: 'otherRaw'})">

  <a href="#/article">
  <a href="#/articles/1234">
  <a href="#/articles/1/?raw='yyy'">
  <a href="#/articles/22/?raw=zzz">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIXAKydpKtTDl1D8hZJe?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that's what I figured. I've [simply resorted to `url: '/raw` for the `article.raw`](https://github.com/afreeorange/bock/blob/master/bock/ui/src/scripts/Bock.routes.js#L94). Thing is, I had forward slashes in the `articleID` (should've called it `articleTitle`, sorry) which leads to [another set of issues entirely](https://github.com/afreeorange/bock#ui-router).

Answer (score 0):

just simple one add infront / like this (/articalraw?raw)

```
.state('article.raw') { url: '/articalraw?raw' controller: 'rawArticleController'}
```

HAppy Coding

Comment: Well, even if you did that, it will still 'swallow' the `?raw` part. I also have slashes in my route (i.e. in `articleID`).